# Facebook publish on my wall/no thank you application dialog

Tags: php, facebook

I have a simple Facebook application that answers a question (for example what is your luck today) with a random score.

What i want to do is showing two simple facebook buttons at the end of the result asking: publish on my wall, and 'no thank you' - so that the user can choose to publish the results on his wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont u put two buttons below 
the one asking to publish,giving it a action to open the publish dialog
eg : http://4rapiddev.com/facebook-graph-api/facebook-publish-to-wall-with-popup-or-dialog-and-call-back/

and 
second button no thank you doing nothing.